# object arguments in Javascript, and how should we name them?

Tags: javascript

in order to increase flexibility and to some degree, modularity in my code, I've begun passing all my arguments around as objects, (I know we have the spread operator in ES6 that also brings some flexibility here and the old arguments array, but I'm enjoying this approach).

example time :

```
var funky = function(options) {
    //... do something with options.query, or options.limit etc
}
```

1. Are there any technical downsides to this approach?
2. what should we name it?  should it be consistent across the codebase so that we always now this signature implies this approach, or should we name it in context ie: for a function that takes some data, 'data', or for a constructor `options` or 'config' etc.

The Concerns I'm considering :

- Maintainability & Flexibility of our API's
- Clarity and readability (there is a sacrifice to this approach)
- argument handling within the function
- performance (not sure if this is even a concern, but curious)

I know this is an slightly opinion based question, but I'm looking to open a discussion from a wider community of developers on how they solve the second hardest problem after cache invalidation, namely, well, naming things.

Comment: I guess name should be per context. A generic name can misdirect based on context.

Comment: How you name it is up to you. But if it's a mish-mash of everything, "options" will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In think that this convention is fine for the callers.
However, you should compensate for the loss of readability from the "hiding" of parameters in the function signature.

The basic step is documenting arguments:

```
// funky arguments:
// query: ...
// limit ...
var funky = function(options) {
}
```

But you have to have the discipline to document *all* arguments. Will everyone touching the code have that discipline ? Probably not.

To enforce the documentation and also detect invalid (removed for instance) arguments, you could add a check step at the start of the functions:

```
var funky = function(options) {

   checkArgs( [ query, //... what is query
                limit, //... what is limit
              ], options );


}
```

`checkArgs` would raise an alarm if `options` contains unknown parameters, so explicitely listing arguments would be mandatory.

For the naming, I'd go with a generic but distinctive name such as `_in` or `_args`.

Comment: I really like that, and toy could intfact store this as a utility with an whitelist object of arrays where the keys correspond to method / function names.  This is particularly cool for isomorpgic functions that get called by the client and run  the server, such as in meteor.

Comment: Agreed re doxumentation, even with a good code review/ pr process when a teams under pressure.....

Comment: Yes, if you like the idea you can build on it (wrappers, mandatory args etc)

Answer (score 1):

Good names for functions and arguments result in self-documenting code. If you have many arguments named "data" with different meanings, then this is not good. A programmer reading the code will have to look for all uses of the variable in order to understand what it means. Therefore, you want to choose variable names that are meaningful within the context of the specific module.

Don't pack a bunch of unrelated variables together into one "data" object just in order to reduce the number of function arguments. Instead, prefer to identify groups of related variables and pack each group with a meaningful name.

Such clean coding techniques are especially important in javascript applications (except for really small ones), because the language doesn't help you with this.

If you find that you need too many function arguments, consider a an object-oriented implementation with setter functions, as follows:

```
function F(x) {
  // This is the constructor
  this.x = x;
}

// These are additional setter functions:
C.prototype.set_a = function(a) {
  this.a = a;
}

C.prototype.set_b = function(b) {
  this.b = b;
}

C.prototype.set_c = function(c) {
  this.c = c;
}

C.prototype.compute = function() {
  // Do something with this.a, this.b and this.c
}
```

Use this "class" as follows:

```
var f = new F(3);
f.set_a(1);
f.set_b(2);
f.set_c(3);
console.log(f.compute());
```

Comment: Agreed, this is very much what I'm leaning toward.  Maintainability does become a concern though as too often we've landed up with a function signature where the third of five arguments becomes  deprecated, which can be a lot of refactoring overhead in a larger system.  It becomes a lot easier to deprecate and incrementally evolve if we pack arguments into an object.  Fair point though, and its maybe worthwhile following a pattern where we always pass options in as a first argument consistent as an object.  This approach does sacrifice some readability though as you point out.

Comment: You could also implement class-like objects in javascript, and then use setter methods in order to pass data to an object.

Comment: Could you show an example. Of what you mean?

Comment: I added an example in the answer